# Regex to get ID from Flickr photo URL?

Tags: php, regex

So I'm trying to create a regex in PHP to get the ID of a photo from its URL.

These are the potential patterns:

```
https://www.flickr.com/photos/12037949754@N01/
        www.flickr.com/photos/12037949754@N01/
            flickr.com/photos/12037949754@N01/
https://www.flickr.com/photos/user/12341234123
        www.flickr.com/photos/user/12341234123
            flickr.com/photos/user/12341234123
```

I'm guessing I use `preg_match`, so something like:

```
if (preg_match("regex", $url, $matches)) {
    return "flickr photo id:" . $matches[x];
}
```

But I'm unsure how to create this regex such that it can return the ID in each situation, so its position in `$matches` is the same each time.

Any ideas? I've had a good look at regex's, but no luck!

Comment: Have you used [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/)? Best way I've found to work out regex solutions is by messing with them on there.

Comment: Does `/([0-9]+[\@a-zA-Z0-9]+)/` do what you need?

Comment: What are the IDs, `12341234123` and `12037949754`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex to pull the ids:

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?flickr\.com\/photos\/(?:user\/)?(\d+)/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jQ5eK3/1

So make the protocol optional, the `www` subdomain optional, and the `user/` optional. Then capture just the number found.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/423621

PHP Usage:

```
$regex = '/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?flickr\.com\/photos\/(?:user\/)?(\d+)/';
$url = 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/user/12341234123';
if (preg_match($regex, $url, $matches)) {
print_r($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to capture photo id for each of your URLs:

```
$regex = '~(?<=/)\d+(?:@\w+)?(?=/|$)~';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP0bD3/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?<=/)     # Positive Lookbehind to make sure / is previous character
\d+        # match 1 or more digits
(?:@\w+)?  # match optional @ followed by a 1 or more word characters
(?=/|$)    # Positive Lookahead to make sure next character is / or end of line
```

Comment: If part after `@` is not part of photo id (though question isn't clear on that) then OP can use: [`(?<=/)\d+(?=[@/]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/dP0bD3/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/([0-9]+[\\@a-zA-Z0-9]+)/",$url,$matches)){
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Example: http://www.regexr.com/3blts

If you don't want the `@N01`, then just:

```
if (preg_match("/([0-9]+)/",$url,$matches)){
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: If you just need to make sure it's flickr, you could do `$parsed = parse_url($url); if ($parsed['host']=='flickr.com'){ //then do the regex }`